# How to debug the "FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Before running the program,I had to run this code in the terminal as shown below:

```
(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>pip install -U pip --user
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\users\user pc\pycharmprojects\testproj\venv\lib\site-packages (19.0.3)

(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>pip install psycopg2 --user
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in c:\users\user pc\pycharmprojects\testproj\venv\lib\site-packages (2.7.7)
```

So, the pip got installed.
Only after running this, I have to run my program, in which the following error is occuring:

```
"C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"
The unique id is 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py", line 381, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(["dscsm047.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could you please be more clear and specific about the process to debug this error as I am very new to this programming field.

Comment: This error message says that programm `dscsm047.exe` cannot be found in your "PATH" environment variable. Type `echo %PATH%` in your terminal/cmd to look into the PATH variable

Comment: May I please know which PATH do I need to mention.. @gdlmx

Comment: Could you please be more clear about the command as I am very new to this. @gdlmx

Comment: I did what you said and I got: ```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMA
GINE 2015\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMAGINE 2015\;C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Pr
ograms\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Python34\Scripts
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message says that programm `dscsm047.exe` cannot be found in your "PATH" environment variable. Please type `echo %PATH%` in your terminal/cmd to look into the PATH variable.

You can probably find the executable file under `C:\DSSAT47\DSCSM047.EXE`
if not, please read the documentation [here](https://dssat.net/tools/tools-for-power-users).

If you actually find `dscsm047.exe` under `C:\DSSAT47`. Then you can run this in the terminal

```
set PATH="C:\DSSAT47;%PATH%"
python  "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"
```

Comment: I have dscsm047.exe in the C:\DSSAT47. But when I run the command echo %PATH% in the terminal I am Getting:

Comment: ```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>echo %PATH%
C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMA
GINE 2015\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Hexagon\ERDAS IMAGINE 2015\;C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Pr
ograms\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\;C:\Python34\Scripts```

Comment: So what next to do? Do I still need to set the path using this command? ```set PATH="C:\DSSAT47;%PATH%"```

Comment: Yes. Because "C:\DSSAT47" is NOT in the list that you pasted here, is it?

Comment: Okay Ill try that

Comment: I got this:  ```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>set PATH="C:\DSSAT47;%PATH%"

(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>python "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or extenal command. So what to do now?

Comment: And while  installing python package error is occuring.

Comment: Maybe call python with its full path "C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe"

Comment: Again I got the same error```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>python "C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: `"C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"`

Comment: Same error again:```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>python "C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.```

Comment: Remove the word `python` at the beginning! Maybe this [tutorial](http://xahlee.info/mswin/env_var.html) will help you with the basics of Command Line usage.

Comment: Yes I did it. ```(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>set PATH="C:\DSSAT47;%PATH%"

(venv) C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj>"C:\Users\user pc\PycharmProjects\testProj\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py"
```

Comment: ERR```The unique id is 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user pc/PycharmProjects/testProj/auto.py", line 381, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(["dscsm047.exe"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\user pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified```

Comment: Again I am getting "FileNotFoundError"

Comment: Maybe you should first try to run `dscsm047.exe` in your terminal. BTW, Are you using CMD.exe?

Comment: Nope I am not using ```CMD.exe```

Comment: Then I know what's wrong... I assume you are using powershell. Please refer to this [article](https://www.build-business-websites.co.uk/set-path-environment-variable-windows-powershell/) to set your `PATH` variable correctly.